# Xcode 6.2 Save As… Dialog Height growing... and growing

Tags: xcode, xcode-6.2

This is a bug that I think was also around in xcode 6.1

1. Create a new file (right click, New File…)
2. Choose anything, say User Interface Empty.
3. Tap on Next button
4. Save As… dialog opens. Tap on Cancel button
5. Repeat from step 3 and height of Save As… dialog grows with each attempt

This would not be a problem if it reset to a default height after creating a file but it doesn't. If you don't drag the bottom of the dialog up it will disappear off the bottom of the screen as far as I can tell.

Is anyone else experiencing this?
Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Did you [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) ?

Comment: That's a known Yosemite bug. Nothing to do with Xcode in particular.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrille I suppose I'll just have to live with it for now (and no, Paul, I haven't filed a bug report. I've wasted too many hours filing reports which have had no satisfactory answers. That's why I love StackOverflow, I answer peoples' questions as often as I can and usually get more or less instant answers to questions I post)